# How to fix required argument missing in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I wrote the following command to create invite link of a guild.

```
 @commands.command()
    async def create_invite(self,ctx,channel: discord.TextChannel):
        invite = await self.bot.channel.create_invite()
        await ctx.send(invite)
```

I am facing the following error:

```
Ignoring exception in command create_invite:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 790, in invoke
    await self.prepare(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 751, in prepare
    await self._parse_arguments(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 670, in _parse_arguments
    transformed = await self.transform(ctx, param)
  File "C:\Users\Rohit\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 516, in transform
    raise MissingRequiredArgument(param)
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: channel is a required argument that is missing.
```

I know this command would work fine if I don't use it inside cogs .I want to know the correct way of using it in cogs.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might come from here:

```py
invite = await self.bot.channel.create_invite()
```

The method you're trying to use is [`TextChannel.create_invite()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=create_invite#discord.TextChannel.create_invite). `self.bot`, which is a [`commands.Bot`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot) object, doesn't have a `channel` attribute so you have this error.

Here's how you'd do it:

```py
@commands.command()
async def create_invite(self, ctx, channel: discord.TextChannel):
    invite = await channel.create_invite()
    await ctx.send(invite)
```